# visual studio 2017 inline temporary variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have code like the following:

```
  using (Process proc = Setupprocess(comtorun))
            {
                proc.Start();
                while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    if (output.Contains("library:"))
                    {
                        collectoutput.Add(output.Split(":")[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

in Visual studio it gave me an option to inline a temporary variable and wanted to rewrite it like the following:

```
  using (Process proc = Setupprocess(comtorun))
            {
                proc.Start();
                while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {

                    if (proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine().Contains("library:"))
                    {
                        collectoutput.Add(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine().Split(":")[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Am i correct when i think that when it calls collectoutput.Add(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine().Split(":")[1]);  that it will actually be reading line 2 of the output and not line 1?

Comment: Yeah its weird it suggested this, i have never seen it personally, and yes you are correct that it will call `ReadLine` Again

Comment: @TheGeneral Thank you, you have stopped a bug before it began

Comment: also a good example of why "command query seperation" is a good thing

Comment: I can't get VS to suggest this; do you have any other tools / addons installed? but yes: you're right about the impact

Comment: @MarcGravell i have almost everything installed that comes with visual studios installer except the c++ and science packages and only the C++ that were absolutely required by other features installed

Comment: @IsaacMorris ah, my bad; I've found how to repro it; just select the variable declaration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLNGo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're absolutely right that this suggestion introduces a code altering change - essentially a bug. Ultimately, there is no inbuilt declarative way of saying that a method in .NET is a pure function. In some cases such a change will be perfectly valid, where-as in others (like this) it will be bad, and *there's no way of knowing which it is in any case* (without starting a manually maintained cheat-sheet of times when this is known-bad or known-good). So: it *offers* this functionality for the times it would be helpful, without forcing it on you (it doesn't appear as a *suggested* change visible by default, for example - it only appears when you actively select the variable).

So, in this case: don't use it.